# PostgreSQL, could not connect to remote server via port 5432

Tags: postgresql, remote

I know other people have posted similar questions but none of the solutions applied here. I have installed Postgresql-9.6 under CentOS 7 on my virtual private server, and I am trying to connect to the server locally by doing:

```
psql -U postgres -h [ip_address]
```

However, I got message like:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on 
[ip_address] and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?.
```

As suggested by previous posts, I went to **postgresql.conf** and set:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      
port = 5432
```

also, I edited **pg_hba.conf** as follows:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

By restart the postgresql server, and doing:

```
netstat -nlt
```

I got:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6969            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

It shows port 5432 is listening. However, I still got same error message when trying to connect to the database locally.

Comment: Did you try with `-h 127.0.0.1`? With other user than  postgres?

Comment: I also tried telnet the server at port 5432 but still, no success. Can anyone tell why from the configuration I have posted?

Comment: no, could it be a firewall rule blocking it?

Comment: Can you try `sudo -u postgres psql` (without nothing else) and  add the error you'll get?

Comment: It turned out to be firewall blocking the port 5432. [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/789014/issues-configuring-firewall-rules-for-postgres-on-centos)